# get specific index when using izip over list

Tags: python, loops

I want to iterate over a list and find the latest "consecutive value".

What does that mean, well:

If I have a list `priceValue = [423, 399, 390, 400, 430, 420, 423]`, my latest consecutive value will be the 2 last indexes: 420 to 423, index number: 5 and 6.

I want to iterate and get the index at the **right place**

at this moment I use:

```
for x, y in itertools.izip(priceValue, priceValue[1:]):

    print x, y
    if y > x:
        #print x, y
        print priceValue.index(y), priceValue.index(x)
```

But my problem is it will only print index "0" and "5" since the value 423 is found at index 0.

How do i get the right index?

NOTE: I can't tag "izip" in tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions#enumerate) which yields index with original items:

```
>>> for i, x in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
...     print i, x  # i: index, x: item
...
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

---

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> xs = [423, 399, 390, 400, 430, 420, 423]
>>> [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.izip(xs, xs[1:])) if y > x]
[2, 3, 5]
>>> [(i, i+1) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.izip(xs, xs[1:])) if y > x]
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

---

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.izip(xs, xs[1:])):
    if y > x:
        print i, i + 1, x, y

# Prints
# 2 3 390 400
# 3 4 400 430
# 5 6 420 423
```

Comment: thanks, but then how will I get the correct x and y? it complains when I copy your solution

Comment: @NutshellProgrammer, `[(i, i+1, x, y) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.izip(xs, xs[1:])) if y > x]` or `[(x, y) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.izip(xs, xs[1:])) if y > x]` depending on your need.

Comment: like this: [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.izip(xs, xs[1:])) if y > x]
      print x, y
      if y > x:
          #print x, y
          timeIndexY = priceValue.index(y)
          print priceValue.index(y), priceValue.index(x)

Comment: @NutshellProgrammer, I added another version that does not use list comprehension, but a plain `for`, `if` statement. Please check it out.

Comment: thank you, I'm getting closer but for some reason:  for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.izip(priceValue, priceValue[1:])):
      if y > x:
          print i, i + 1, x, y
          newX = i
          newY = i + 1
          #print priceValue.index(newY), priceValue.index(newX)


gives: print priceValue.index(newY), priceValue.index(newX)
ValueError: 1 is not in list

Comment: @NutshellProgrammer, You don't need to use `index(...)` to get index, because there is `i` (index of `x`)

Comment: THANK YOOUUUU SOOOO much

Answer (score 0):

```
[(i, i+1) for i in range(len(priceValue)-1) if priceValue[i]<priceValue[i+1]]
```

Output :

```
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Or more quite :

```
res=[({i:priceValue[i], i+1:priceValue[i+1]}) for i in range(len(priceValue)-1) if priceValue[i]<priceValue[i+1]]
```

Output :

```
[{2: 390, 3: 400}, {3: 400, 4: 430}, {5: 420, 6: 423}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind avoiding for loops, you can also find the last consecutive value by calculating differences:

```
import numpy as np
x = [423, 399, 390, 400, 430, 420, 423]
d = np.diff(x)
```

The index you want is the last positive index:

```
np.where(d > 0)[0][-1]
>>> 5
```